# Message not always appearing in input error

Tags: c++, string, input

Why does the "Error: Must introduce 1 or 0" message appear only every 2 times and not always?

```
int instruction() {
    string instruction;
    cout << "Do you want to see the tutorial of the game? If yes press: 1, else press: 0" << endl << "--> ";
    while (getline(cin,instruction)){
        if (instruction == "1" ||  instruction == "0") {
            break;
        }else{
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
                cout << "Error: Must introduce 1 or 0" << endl << "--> ";
            }
    }
```

Debugging output:

```
Do you want to see the tutorial of the game? If yes press: 1, else press: 0
--> asdasd
asdasdasd
Error: Must introduce 1 or 0
--> sdfasdfasdf
asdf
Error: Must introduce 1 or 0
--> sad
fasd
Error: Must introduce 1 or 0
--> fas
df
Error: Must introduce 1 or 0
--> asd
fas
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to differentiate between a successful input of `0` or `1` and that the `while (getline(cin,instruction))` failed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line you enter is eaten by `getline(cin,instruction)`, so `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');` waits for you to enter a second line and the eats it. Simply remove the `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');` since the `getline` call already consumes the bad input.

Comment: Cargo cult programming. :-(